# Configuring Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have loadbalancer server and edges. I am trying to configure reverse proxy in order to hide the backend servers PL1,2,3. PL 1,2,3 are not located in same subnet. They are located in different locations.

```
       PL1
Lb1 -> PL2
       PL3
```

I tried to configure Apache reverse proxy but it is not sending request to PL1,2,3. Reverse proxy worked only when I configured apache to send request to local server on other port.

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /PL1 http://PL1server.com/
ProxyPassReverse /PL1 http://PL1server.com/
```

The above configuration did not worked. Could you help me to solve the issue. Or is there other proxy types like Squid,Socks5 to solve this issue.

Does the reverse proxy fails if we use IP address or domain URL in ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse ?

Comment: Where are these settings configured?  What do you mean when you say it didn't work - what behavior or error messages are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a proxy balancer?

```
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / ballancer://mycluster/
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://PL1:80
BalancerMember http://PL2:80
BalancerMember http://PL3:80
</Proxy>
```